# Difference between pyramid and statsmodels fit() and ARIMA()?

Tags: python, data-science, statsmodels, pyramid-arima

I'm currently using ARIMA with pyramid, and when creating an ARIMA object using pyramid's ARIMA() I can sepcify an exogenous parameter, but when calling fit() I cannot specify an exogenous variable.

However with statsmodels, I saw that this is reversed.  I cannot specify an exogenous parameter with ARIMA() yet I can specify one with fit().

If I would like to include an exogenous parameter for both ARIMA() and fit(), which one should I use?

Answer (score 4):

There are several differences between statsmodels' `ARIMA` class and pyramid's ([recently renamed](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/pull/46) to `pmdarima`):

- First of all, statsmodels' `ARIMA` class has no seasonal component. `pmdarima`'s `ARIMA` class allows seasonality optionally. It's an all-in-one wrapper for the statsmodels `ARMA`, `ARIMA` and `SARIMAX`
- Statsmodels takes data in the constructors, but `pmdarima` adheres to more of a scikit-learn signature, which accepts only model hyper-parameters in the signature and the data in the `fit` call.

It's important to note that when you pass `exogenous` to `pmdarima`'s `fit` call, it *is* internally passing the exogenous array to the underlying `ARIMA` class.

#### tl;dr

When you use `pmdarima`, it is using statsmodels under the hood. Just pass the data to the `fit` method.